# Compile multiple JPEGs into a PDF, given numbering: Page 1, Page 2, Page 3, etc.

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

I have multiple different ways to compile JPEGS into a PDF, the easiest being the Acrobat suite.  However, the numbering schema of my JPEG files goes Page 1, Page 2, Page 3, etc.

As a result, the default ordering of the compilation goes: Page 1, Page 11, Page 111 on Adobe Acrobat.  Despite trying numerous programs, none of them had the basic capability of sorting by any other heuristic.  I downloaded a Bulk Renaming Tool, hoping to find a way to change the naming schema, but couldn't figure out a way to resolve it.

Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: There are many mass renamers available, and any of them should be able to accomplish the trivial task of zero-padding your filenames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Python, you could rename your files using leading zeros so they would sort properly like this:

```
import glob
import os

for f in glob.glob("Page *"):
    os.rename(f, "Page %03d" % (int(f.split()[1])))
```

If the numbers in your file names have more than three digits, increase the 03 in %03d as required.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you are needing a user interface of some sort instead of a programming type approach yes?

Have you tried [pdfcreator](http://www.pdfforge.org/pdfcreator) and use the wait and collect option once you print to it the first time. Then at the end consolidate and render the job.

I usually open the print queue and pause the queue then use up and down arrows in the interface to sort jobs/pages in different order before combining and spitting it out.